# DOMException: "Node was not found" error when using JQuery flickity slider in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, flickity

I'm using the Flickity slider in ReactJS (maybe you ask why I'm using a jquery library in React? because slick slider does not support RTL, and my website is RTL, and it's important to me to see carousels are starting from the right, and also slick RTL issue is already open in Github so I didn't have any choice...)

this error happens when I change the route, and the number of the items in the slider is not too much to initiate the slider, but when I refresh the page it will work well!

all of the Flickity React components had an issue and other official React carousel sliders had RTL issue

Comment: I am getting this when i am rebuilding the jQuery nestable tree.